# Custom Settings in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, seekbar

I want to make a section in my app to allow the user to specify a range of time. I'm trying to make the design to something like android timers at the moment, but I'm having trouble. Would I need to make a custom preference for the design, or would I need to use SharedPreferences in a Fragment?

[Image of Android Clock Design](https://img.gadgethacks.com/img/15/02/63568848111004/0/get-android-ms-new-clock-app-any-device-right-now.w1456.jpg)

Additional Question:I'm using a Crystal double range seekbar that is visible when I run the app, but it doesn't show when in Android XML design.

Comment: Android Studio is _NOT_ Android. Android Studio is an _IDE_

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting your usecase here. As far my understand, you need a screen to ask the user to the enter the date range like date from & to. If so, my suggestion would have the different screen to get those values and storre those in a SQLite.

Comment: Is there a general rule of thumb as when to use SQLite vs Preferences? I was following Android's Settings as a guideline and they didn't mention too much about SQLite there.. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Overview

Comment: Shared preferences can only store key-value pairings whilst an SQLite database is much more flexible. So shared preferences are particularly useful for storing user preferences, should the app display notifications etc. Whilst an SQLite database is useful for just about anything.
Both data sources are local but something you should be aware of is the ability to backup your application data to cloud storage that is linked to the user's Google account. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Alright thank you. Also, since SharedPreference need a key would we be able to use them if an item needed to be added programmatically?Like we had a user sign in page where we allow users to add as many accounts as they want. Even though the set up is simple(just a username and a password), we'd handle that withSQLite still?